# Subprocess.Popen behaves differently in interpreter, executable scripts

Tags: python, subprocess

Let's say you have the following:

```
command = shlex.split("mcf -o -q -e -w %s %s" % (SOLFILE, NETFILE))
task = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = task.communicate()
print "stdout: %s" % stdout #debugging
print "stderr: %s" % stderr #debugging
if stderr:
    sys.exit("MCF crashed on %s" % NETFILE)
```

It's not necessary to know what mcf is, except that it's a C program which will overflow if it's not given a satisfiable netfile.  (Why can't I just ensure that all the netfiles are satisfiable?  Well, because the easiest way to check that is to feed it to mcf and see if it overflows...)

Anyway, when I run this in an executable script, task.communicate() doesn't seem to store anything in stdout and stderr.  (To be precise, I get stdout == stderr == ''.)  Instead, the stderr stream from mcf seems to be "leaking" to the terminal rather than getting captured by the subprocess pipe.  Here's some sample output to illustrate:

```
Netfile: facility3cat_nat5000_wholesaler_capacitation_test_.net
Solfile: facility3cat_nat5000_wholesaler_capacitation_test_.sol
*** buffer overflow detected ***: mcf terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
...
...[fifty lines of Linda Blair-esque output]...
...
stdout: None
stderr: 
...[program continues, since stderr did not evaluate to True]...
```

This only fails when running the script from the command line.  When I step through it line by line in the interpreter, stdout and stderr are correctly assigned:

```
>>> task = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> stdout, stderr = task.communicate()
>>> stderr
'*** buffer overflow detected ***: mcf terminated\n======= Backtrace: =========\n'
...[more headspinning and vomit]...
```

Could anyone help me to understand why this works in the interpreter, but not when executed?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Modified my answer to indicate the testing I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little test script to test the `subprocess` module with.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo echo to stderr 1>&2
echo echo to stdout
```

Then I wrote a small Python script that calls it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

command = ('./joe.sh',)
task = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = task.communicate()
print 'stdout == %r\nstderr == %r' % (stdout, stderr)
```

The output of running it looks just like this:

```
$ python joe.py 
stdout == 'echo to stdout\n'
stderr == 'echo to stderr\n'
```

The output of running that same sequence in `ipython` is the same.

So the `subprocess` module is behaving in the manner you expect, and not how it's behaving for you in your question. I think something other than the `subprocess` module must be at fault here because what you're doing works for me.

I'm running Python 2.7, so another possibility is that maybe there is some kind of weird bug in older versions of the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Thanks, I just caught that too.  Fixed the post to reflect that..  When stdout is redirected, it still works in the interpreter, and still doesn't at the command line.

Comment: @Omnifarious Yep, command is the same.  In fact, I get the same buffer overflow error, just that in the interpreter it gets caught and assigned to stderr, and at the command line it's dumped to the screen.

Comment: @W voq - This is quite odd. I think I'm going to delete my answer soon because I can't figure out what the matter is. It works for me with a little shell script I wrote that spits stuff out to `stdout` and `stderr`

Comment: @Omnifarious Thanks your all of your help with this.  I've accepted your answer since it helped me to determine that it was the invoked process and not the subprocess module that was leaking.

Comment: @wvoq: I figured it was something like that. And I provided the detailed demonstration so you would have a good diagnostic tool for figuring that out. I'm glad it helped. :-)