# subprocess.Popen unexpected behavior

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I inherited some Python code which uses subprocess.Popen to print a pdf file using Adobe Reader. The code has worked well for years running on Windows 7, I am getting it set up on Windows 10. For some reason the call to Popen starts an Adobe Reader process, but does not open the application. The code works as expected if I run it from the Python interpreter. But when it when it is running as a Windows process, Adobe Reader does not open, or print the pdf. I checked the command line parameters for the running process and it is invoked exactly the same as when run from the Python Interpreter. A code snippet is below.

```
printFileName = r'"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /p /h /t '
printFileName = printFileName + filename
subprocess.Popen(printFileName)
```

filename is the full path to a .pdf file.

I'm not really sure where to even begin figuring this out so any pointers or suggestions on how to improve the question would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe try adding `stdout` and `stderr` to the `Popen` command to see if any output and errors are getting passed: `task = subprocess.Popen(printFileName, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE); stdout, stderr = task.communicate();
print 'stdout == %r\nstderr == %r' % (stdout, stderr)`, reference: [Subprocess.Popen behaves differently in interpreter, executable scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043857/subprocess-popen-behaves-differently-in-interpreter-executable-scripts)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try this in the morning.